# Are evaluations of expressions in member initialization sequenced with respect to each other?

Tags: c++, constructor, member, language-lawyer

Specifically, say I have:

```
struct X { X(int i) { cout << i; } };
int f() { cout << 'f'; return 0; }
int g() { cout << 'g'; return 1; }

struct Z {
    Z() : a(f()), b(g()) {}
    X a, b;
};

int main() { Z z; cout << '\n'; }
```

I know that the constructors of the members are guaranteed to be invoked in the order they are defined in the `struct`, so `0` will be printed before `1`.
But how about the evaluation of their arguments? Is it guaranteed to be:

```
f0g1
```

? Or, perhaps,

```
fg01
```

and

```
gf01
```

are also valid outputs?

References to the standard are appreciated.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I don't really care for differences between the standards. It's the intention which matters, which is likely didn't change, only made clearer.

Comment: Makes sense, as far as I can tell the behavior should be the same and as you suggest *C++11* just made it explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) each member initializer is a full-expression so all side effects have to take effect before the next one is evaluated.

Section `12.6.2` *Initializing bases and members* paragraph *7* says:

> [...]The initialization performed by each mem-initializer constitutes a full-expression. Any
>   expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as part of the full-expression that performs the initialization.[...]

and section `1.9` *Program execution* paragraph *14* says:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

The relevant grammar from section `12.6.2` is as follows:

```
ctor-initializer:
   : mem-initializer-list
mem-initializer-list:
   mem-initializer ...opt
   mem-initializer , mem-initializer-list ...opt
[...]
```

Pre *C++11* the same wording on each *mem-initializer* being a full-expression is not there, at least not in the oldest draft standard available [1804](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf). But as far as I can tell the same logic I used in [Are multiple mutations of the same variable within initializer lists undefined behavior pre C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19881804/1708801) applies in this case as well and so we should expect the same behavior pre *C++11* as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard

> The initialization performed by each mem-initializer constitutes a
>   full-expression. Any expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as
>   part of the full-expression that performs the initialization

So at first there will be executed full expression a(f()) and after that the full expression b(g()) .

As the result output has to be

```
f0g1
```