# Interdependent initialization with commas?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Is the following perfectly defined:

```
int x = 42, y = x;
```

i.e. strictly equivalent to:

```
int x = 42;
int y = x;
```

EDIT : the question is not about style (I know that it's wrong...), the question is "theoretical"

Comment: See: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL04-C.+Do+not+declare+more+than+one+variable+per+declaration

Comment: @Deduplicator Why not? Isn't each declarator sequenced?

Comment: Related? http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1342

Comment: @Damon: That's the stupidest thing I've seen all day. "Don't write code because you will confuse people who don't understand code", it may as well say.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: given that many people argue that the code in the OP's question hss undefined behavior, is a code-style standard that requires separate declarations really all that idiotic?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: On the contrary. Unless you never plan to work with another human, you have to plan for the possibility that someone else is slightly less genious than you are and _does_ understand the intent of your code wrong. If your code lends to that, you're a bad coder. It's the same principle as with using redundant parenthesis. Because, hey, you know operator precedence, and everybody who doesn't is a loser, so there is no real need, is there. But truth is, if others can't identify your intent correctly at the first glance, it's your failure, not theirs.

Comment: @Damon: I plan to work with other humans _who are programmers_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's nice, but... _programmers_ like e.g. the guy who literally invented the C++ language suggest that you use one declaration per line and that while you should know the most basic precedence rules, you should parenthese them to avoid any doubt. They suggest that because they realize that even _they_ don't remember every rule 100% correctly at all times, and in particular someone else who might not have 4 decades of experience might not.

Comment: @Damon: Appeal to authority for style guides; awesome. BTW, while Bjarne originally invented "C with Classes" and developed it into what later became pre-standard C++, _hundreds of people_ created the C++ we know today. Just so you're aware.

Comment: I updated my answer extensively, this seems to be unspecified using the current language, although.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It seems like they are.

Comment: @juanchopanza well more precisely, I can not find a normative reference that proves they are although it seems more than likely they are meant to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct answer is that

```
int x = 42, y = x;
```

and

```
int x = 42;
int y = x;
```

**are usually equivalent (not strictly).**

---

Considering the standard **§ 8 Declarators [dcl.decl]**:

> *`3` Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.*

and in the footnote [100] further explains:

> *A declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to the corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single
>   declarator. That is*
>
> *T D1, D2, ... Dn;*
>
> **is usually equivalent to**
>
> *T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;*
>
> *where T is a decl-speciﬁer-seq and each Di is an init-declarator.*

- The above guarantees that `x = 42` and `y = x` will be evaluated separately. However, as [@Praetorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241631/praetorian) correctly pointed out in the comments, footnotes are not normative.
- This means that the order of evaluation is not well defined and an implementer could as well implement the evaluation of the declarations in the reverse order (i.e,. `T Dn; ...T D2; T D1;`).
- One might argue that the comma operator is guaranteed left to right evaluation. However, this not the case. According to the K & R [K & R II, 3.6 p.63], that also applies to C++:

> > > *The commas that separate function arguments, variables in declarations, etc., are not comma operators, and do not guarantee left to right evaluation.*

Comment: Footnotes are non-normative. I think the *usually* in the footnote leaves enough wiggle room for an implementation to evaluate them in the reverse order, and still be compliant.

Comment: @Praetorian I agree with the non-normativeness of footnotes, but the quote from the standard clearly states they're analysed separately.

Comment: Yes, that's very clear. But evaluating `T D1, D2, ... Dn;` as `T Dn; ... T D2; T D1;` is also analyzing them separately.

Comment: @Praetorian isn't comma sequential evaluation left to right?

Comment: The *comma operator* is. But this is not the comma operator, here's it just a separator for *init-declarators* - §8/1 The *init-declarator-list* appearing in a declaration is a comma-separated sequence of declarators

Comment: "usually equivalent, not strictly" - so you are saying that there is a possibility that `y` will not be initialized to `42`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb interpretation of the standard implies that yes `y` might not be initialized to 42. It depends on how the order of the evaluation is implemented.

Comment: But, if the order of initialisation would not be granted, could the compiler really chose int y=x;int x=42 as alternative (x would be undefined) ?  Or otherwhise stated, could int y=x, x=42 be a valid expression ?

Comment: @Christophe `y = x, x = 42` is not a valid expression. As such the compiler in this case would generate an error.

Comment: True: it's not valid if the order is from left to right.  Clang++ warns because x would be uninitialised, and Visual C++ does not even compile it because he states that the x is not yet defined.

Comment: @MattMcNabb well since that text is not normative we can not prove or disprove anything based on it. Based on the text as I say it looks unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

This question came up in [comp.lang.c++.moderated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c++.moderated) a long time ago under the topic [init-declarator-list analysis order](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/vR-BEaEYKII/0f07LEXIC9IJ) and the conclusion there was `Yes`.

Although I see the *full-expression* argument but I do not see the order of evaluation argument. So I think this is unspecified.

The relevant part of the question is:

> In this declaration and definition:
>
> int a = 2, b = a;
>
> Is it guaranteed that b will always be initialized as 2 ? If yes, then
>   can we say that a = 2 is always analysed(or evaluated?) before b = a ?

and the relevant part of the answer is:

> Yes.  Strictly stated, the observable behavior of the program must be
>   as if all of the side effects of the 'a = 2' part of the declaration
>   took place before the evaluation of the 'b = a' part starts.  (In
>   practice, of course, in this simple example, a compiler could assign 2
>   to both a and b in any order, or even in parallel, because doing so
>   would result in the same observable behavior.)

and further down:

> In this particular case, however, it does separate the declarator
>   list into separate declarators; each declarator contains a complete
>   expression, and the declarators are evaluated in order.

**Update**

What makes each *init-declator* a *full expression* is subtle but as far as I can tell follows the same logic I used in [Are multiple mutations of the same variable within initializer lists undefined behavior pre C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881803/are-multiple-mutations-of-the-same-variable-within-initializer-lists-undefined-b). In this case we start from the grammar defined in ection *8*:

```
init-declarator-list:
  init-declarator
  init-declarator-list , init-declarator
init-declarator:
  declarator initializeropt
```

The next point of focus is the *initializer* grammar which is covered in section `8.5`:

```
initializer:
  brace-or-equal-initializer
  ( expression-list )
brace-or-equal-initializer:
  = initializer-clause
  braced-init-list
initializer-clause:
  assignment-expression
  braced-init-list
```

In both cases we have *= initializer-clause* which bring us to *assignment-expression* which if we follow the grammar in section *5* bring us back to *primary-expression* which can give us either a *literal* or *id-expression*.

So we do indeed have full-expressions separated by a grammatical comma so we have:

```
int x = 42, y = x;
          ^      ^
          |      end full-expression
          end full-expression
```

and according to section `1.9` paragraph *14* we see that:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a
>   full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.<sup>8.</sup>

As for the order of evaluation, I think this is not specified, the same logic that applies to [defect report 430](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#430) for initializer lists would seem to apply here as well. In C++11 the language for initializer lists was fixed with the following addition in section `8.5.4`:

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. [...]

there is no such equivalent for *initializer*.

Comment: I like it much better now that it gets into the details of what the Standard says. Yet, I'm not sure how you refute my original criticism: The initializer is an expression, not the initialization.

Comment: The initializer is a declarator not an expression since it does not come up section `5` but it can contain and expression and each expression will be a full expression since it is not a sub-expression.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's my whole point :) where does the Standard guarantee that initialization is done in order?

Comment: See also [CWG active #1342](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1342), which I linked in comments to the OP.

Comment: But the initialization of `x` is not part of the full-expression `42` neither a side effect of the expression, is it?

Comment: @dyp I agree, the order of evaluation is unspecified, updated answer.

Comment: I think it *should* be defined. So either we're missing something, or the Standard's too vague. Either way, maybe a question on the Standard's mailing list could help.

Comment: @dyp I wonder if section `3.3.2 p1` implies the ordering, I could see how it could be read that way. The subsequent paragraphs also read as if an order if implied.

Comment: `int x = 5; int y = x;` *must* be well-defined behaviour. It seems this is only specified via [stmt.stmt]/1 "Except as indicated, statements are executed in sequence." which does not apply to `int x = 5, y = x;` -- I would say that 3.3.2/1 mostly specifies name lookup, not initialization. But I agree it's probable that the *intention* is to sequence multiple init-declarators.