# Using previous element's value in an array's initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, array-initialization, aggregate-initialization

So I've found [this code works](https://ideone.com/Boayfx):

```
int foo[] = {0, foo[0] + 1, foo[1] + 2, foo[2] + 4 };
```

Is this officially legal? I thought that I was making an `initializer_list` here, but if I can access previously initialized elements this must be doing aggregate initialization.

I tried to find an official statement on the legality of this, but I couldn't seem to.

Comment: [You have already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828350/can-i-reference-previous-members-of-an-initializer-list)

Comment: It seems that duplicate is from 2015, and the answer to this question disagrees with the linked duplicate. This makes me wonder what is the proper way to request an update on an old question when changes to the language make that question's answers incorrect?