# C Increment Operator Explanation

Tags: c, increment, post-increment, pre-increment, sequence-points

On executing this piece of C command, the output of **num** is 7. I was expecting it to be 6, can anyone explain why and how it turns out to be 7?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int i = 0, num = 0;
    num = a[++i + a[++i]] + a[++i];
    printf("%d ", i);
    printf("%d ", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior - you cannot modify same variable twice between in the same operation.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question within the same hour? (Granted, you phrased it much better this time. :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, the expression : `a[++i+a[++i]]`, involves the increment of the variable `i` two times, and comes out to be `a[i + 2 + a[i + 2]]`, which is `a[0 + 2 + a[2]] = a[4] = 4`, and the second operand, `a[++i]` becomes `a[3]`, which is equal to 3, hence, the final answer is 7. In other words, this is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is incremented 3 times within the same expression in `num = a[++i + a[++i]] + a[++i];`

This has undefined behavior in C.  It is a moot point trying to explain why it outputs `7` or `6` or anything whatsoever. *Undefined behavior* can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

llvm on OS X gives me 6 and a warning:

```
wi.c:5:8: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
```

which suggests that we are looking at an undefined behavior.  The exact nature of what it undefined here is not clear to me thus far, but feels a bit irrelevant.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19862240/4045754) explains and provides links for why this is undefined behavior and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0;
num = a[ ++i + a[++i]] + a[++i]
```

Will evaluate to

```
num = a[1+ a[2]] + a[3]
num = a[1 + 2] + a[3]
num = a[3] + a[3]
num = 3 + 3
num = 6
```

Comment: @Antti Haapala How come ?

Comment: See the duplicate question and its answer.

Comment: @Antti Haapala Yes, you are right. Thankyou