# program execution is not started at main()

Tags: c++

I developed many years in C and only now discovered that a program can execute code prior to main() function.
Here is a code example

```
int generateNum(){
    // Some malicious code here...
    return 5;
}

static int someArray[] = {generateNum(),generateNum()}  

int main(){
     // Some code here...
}
```

The function `generateNum()` is called twice before `main()`.

My questions are

1. Who calls generateNum()? I know that on Windows it is crtexe()
2. Is this behavior standardized on different platforms: Windows/Linux/Android/iOS?
3. How can I get more information about this behavior? I want to search in Google, but I don't know how to describe it.
4. Can I do anything I want inside the generateNum()? I mean, can I call malloc()? What about fopen() and fwrite()?  Can I open a socket and send information over UDP? Eventually I can abuse this function and even call to main() from it :-)

Comment: static objects are initialized before main is entered, as per the standard (C++ standard as far as I am certain, but I think C as well).

Comment: In fact, dummy statics can be used to invoke certain code from their constructors before main is entered.

Comment: See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783404/is-main-really-start-of-a-c-program

Comment: The caveat is that you don't know in which order initialization is performed. It can even change between compiles on the same machine, depending on the link order, object file layout and the phase of the moon.

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language. -1 for a fictituous question that [makes no sense](http://ideone.com/mrbsQK).

Comment: @JvO Though only between different translation units, no? In a single file it should be well-defined, shouldn't it?

Comment: This code is not valid C. In that language global initialisers have to be constant, so `main` *is* the first user-provided code to be executed.

Comment: @ChristianRau In a single file it's in order of declaration within the file.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it... Compilers have large amount of freedom in optimizing their code. It object are dependant on another I would use singletons so the order doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JvO At least you can (or should) count on what the standard says. The standard can never be optimized away by any amount of freedom.

Comment: Hmm, okay. But I still wouldn't *rely* on it...

Comment: @JvO in C the order of evaluation in an intialization list [is unspecified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881803/are-multiple-mutations-of-the-same-variable-within-initializer-lists-undefined-b) but in C++ it is [well defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442894/are-multiple-mutations-within-initializer-lists-undefined-behavior). There is even a sequence point after each initializer.

Comment: @JvO: If you cannot *rely* on what the standard requires there is little you can do in programming. That being said, I rarely rely on compilers doing the right thing with complex templates... but they have proven to implement their own *flavors* of the standard. At any rate I don't know of any compiler that does not follow the top-down initialization order mandated by the standard *within a single translation unit*, except where extensions in the compiler allow you to force some different ordering. As a matter of fact, initialization of `cin` and `cout` depend on this order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. C++ guarantees that such initialisations take place before `main`. This can be taken care of by the operating system loader/linker, or by some special module linked against the object file that contained `main`.  For gcc, this is described here:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html
2. Not quite.  C++11, 3.6.2.4 (basic.start.init): *It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main.*  Note that initialization takes place before you can ever access that value, though, especially before there is any notion of reference to an entity in the same compilation unit.
3. [basic.start.init] in the language standard is what you want to have a look at.  The behaviour here is *dynamic initialization* for variables with *static storage duration*.

Comment: Can I call malloc() from initialization function? What about fopen() and fwrite()?  Can I open a socket and send information over UDP?

Comment: @DanielHsH, no to all of the things you mentioned.

Comment: P.s., I just tried malloc() and it works on windows and linux.

Comment: @DanielHsH, I would expect it to work (since many container classes that you may want to use will use dynamic memory allocation), but I don't know-- C++ has many rules and exceptions.  However:  Since we're talking about a C++ exclusive feature here, you don't want to use `malloc()`; instead, use `new` and `new[]` unless you have a very good reason not to (e.g., interfacing with C code that does `free`).

Answer (score 7):

> A program shall contain a global function called main, *which is the designated start of the program.*

It doesn't say that no code executes before `main` is called. Full quote:

> 3.6.1  Main function                                [basic.start.main]
>
> 1 A  program  shall  contain a global function called main, which is
>   the   designated start of the program.  It is implementation-defined
>   whether   a  program  in a freestanding environment is required to
>   define a main   function.  [Note: in a freestanding environment,
>   start-up and termination  is  implementation-defined;  *start-up 
>   contains the execution of   constructors for objects of namespace
>   scope with static storage  duration;  termination  contains  the
>   execution of destructors for objects   with static storage duration*. 
>   ]